# MySQL LEFT JOIN display duplicate rows

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue with an MySQL left join it returns duplicate rows for the same name. 
[image: http://gyazo.com/d63ffe70dd6930674e608e43a409aade]

```
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT
            w.id AS 'WheelID',
            w.name AS 'Name',
            i.id AS 'ImageID',
            i.image_url AS 'Image'
            FROM `rims` AS w
            LEFT JOIN `rims_images` AS i ON
            (w.`id` = i.`mid`)
            WHERE w.`id` =  '".$model."'

           ");
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

                   echo $row['Name'];
                echo $row['Image'];

            }
```

Thank you any help will gladly be appreciated.

Comment: What results do you desire?

Comment: If there are multiple matches, `LEFT JOIN` will return all of them, just like `INNER JOIN` does. Why do you expect anything different?

Comment: I am going for displaying the Name and just the image below.

Comment: well thats normal since its one to many meaning rims is attached to multiple rims_images so in a single join its expected this way. One thing could be done is to group data from rims_images

Comment: If there are 3 images of the same rim, which one should it display?

Comment: Your question is misleading. You're not getting duplicate rows in the result. Each result has a different `ImageID` and `Image`.

Comment: @Barmar I am trying to display the name of the rim and show all the different images for that particular rim.

Comment: Your left join displays duplicates, because your left table contains duplicates of the columns you are querying. if you only want one resultrow per name, you can add a `GROUP BY w.name`. You should however be aware that you have several images matching one name, so you should either rethink your structure, or decide which one to pick. Otherwise you will get a "randomly" chosen image matching the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only display the Name once in the loop:

```
$first = true;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if ($first) {
        echo $row['Name'];
        $first = false;
    }
    echo $row['Image'];
}
```

Comment: this only works for the first name. if you want it to work for several distinct names, you need to store the last name read and check against the current row.

Comment: The query only returns one rim, because it has `WHERE w.id = $model`. The answer would be different if he were listing multiple rims, I've written that type of loop many times in other answers.

Answer (score -1):

Add **DISTINCT** to query after your SELECT.

That will filter out your duplicates from results.

Comment: He's not getting duplicates. He's getting 3 different images.

Comment: But there are no duplicates. He has three rows which happen to have the same value for the first column, but different values for the second column. `DISTINCT` will not help him here - he needs to figure out what he's trying to get from the database.

Comment: no distinct does not solve the issue is one-to-many issue , in a single join query it will join both tables and will return all matching data.

Comment: in general, distinct should be used with caution because distinct records are not always distinct records