# mysqli left join duplicate row

Tags: php, mysql

table com

```
id | com       | id_status  
1    testing 1   1  
2    testing 2   1  
3    testing 3   2  
4    testing 4   2
```

table update

```
id_status | update  
1           update 1  
2           update 2  
3           update 3  


SELECT `update`.`update`, `com`.`com` as comen
FROM `update` 
    LEFT JOIN `com` ON `update`.`id_status`=`com`.`id_status`
```

it results :

```
update 1  
testing 1  
update 1  
testing 2  
update 2  
testing 3  
update 2  
testing 4
```

the update table results duplicate

i've done using group by `update`.`id_status`, it results :

```
update 1  
testing 1  
testing 2  
update 3
```

the table com only resut 1 row

**EDIT--**
i got syntax from this [MySQL LEFT JOIN display duplicate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301264/mysql-left-join-display-duplicate-rows)

```
$first = true;  
while($row = $query->fetch_object()){  
if($first){  
    echo $row->update;  
    $first = false;  
    echo "<br>";  
}  
echo $row->comen;  
echo "<br>";  
}  

update 1  
testing 1  
testing 2  
testing 3  
testing 4
```

it fetch only 1 table row

**i want the results looks like this :**

```
update 1  
testing 1  
testing 2  
update 2  
testing 3  
testing 4  
update 3  
...
```

**--**

how the right syntax work or maybe the query?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13997365/sql-joins-as-venn-diagram - this will help you understand what joins do. Further to this https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/ <--- a better diagram with data.

Comment: i've seen it before... in fact i've take the pic to learn it. it used left join.. and i've read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23301264/mysql-left-join-display-duplicate-rows  if $first = true  it's only fetch 1 table row

Comment: That question relates to PHP, not SQL. The fact is, you have two fields in your select - the SQL query is going to return every combination that it has that matches your selection criteria (where clause).

Comment: so i've edit the question. you might want to explain it with the code, i kinda confused with text.

Comment: relate to your description is there any magic/trick script?

Comment: @faddi can you format your result so it is easy to understand.

Comment: @RakeshKumar done, it will be the last time i edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This, I think this will resolve:-

```
SELECT `update`.`update`, group_concat(`com`.`com`) as comen
FROM `update` 
    LEFT JOIN `com` ON `update`.`id_status`=`com`.`id_status` 
Group by `update`.`update`
```

and use your php as like:-

```
while($row = $query->fetch_object()){  
    echo $row->update;  
    $comen = explode(",", $row->comen);
    foreach($comen as $values){
     echo "<br>";  
     echo $values;
    }
    echo "<br>";  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use INNER JOIN instead of left join

```
SELECT `update`.`update`, `com`.`com` as comen
FROM `update` INNER JOIN `com` ON `update`.`id_status`=`com`.`id_status`;
```

or can use DISTINCT keyword to avoid duplicate results

```
SELECT DISTINCT `com`.`id_status`, `update`.`update`, `com`.`com` as comen
FROM `update` LEFT JOIN `com` ON `update`.`id_status`=`com`.`id_status`;
```

Comment: i've also tried DISTINCT and it doesn't work wonder why? here's the pic different queries name and tables but same result http://s61.photobucket.com/user/codename_faddi/media/try_zpsms10e3bf.png.html?filters[user]=146246261&filters[recent]=1&sort=1&o=0

Answer (score 0):

According to your query , the result should have ok. Let have a look that the table **com** contain two value those **id_status=1**.

Now if you leftjoin **com** table with **update** table then the query will give 2 row corresponding id_status=1 because  **com**  table contain two row which id_status is 1.

if you want to get only any one row accroding to id_status then you have to use **group by update.id-status** or **group by com.id-status**

```
 SELECT `up`.`up`, `com`.`com` as comen FROM `up` LEFT JOIN `com` ON `up`.`id_status`=`com`.`id_status` group by up.id_status
```

I used up instead of update because update is a keyword.
Table:

[image: com table] [image: Up table]

Result:

[image]

Comment: yes, i've done it using group by only fetch 1 row of table com but not all... i'm kinda frustating with such noob question

Comment: Could you tell again what do u want actually ?

Comment: i want to fetch all everything loop each 1 row table update with each all table com. some say loop a query is an expensive way

Comment: Unfortunately, it is ok from my side. I don't know what problem is going on in your ? I executed the query in my mysql server . See the update query and result which i executed .

Comment: here's my code http://i61.photobucket.com/albums/h48/codename_faddi/try2_zpszw8zhikd.png?t=1488360365 . need to fetch all com in each update